# Having some troubles with my chemical reactions ODE code

Tags: python, ode

So I'm writing my masters thesis and I have to model the BR (Briggs-Rauscher iodine-iodide oscillation) reaction and I have some problems with this code. Everytime I run(the same code) it, I get a different plot and an error. I tried different points and different variations but still the same.

```
lsoda--  at current t (=r1), mxstep (=i1) steps   
       taken on this call before reaching tout     
      in above message,  i1 =       500
******** ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type). 
  Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
  warnings.warn(warning_msg, ODEintWarning)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I don't know where I went wrong.

Thank you in advance and sorry for all your troubles.  Thanks for all the answers so far.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

k1 = 3.1*(10**12) #M**-2 s**-1 - k11
k2 = 2.2  #s**-1 - k1-1
k3 = 5.0*10**9 #M**-2 s**-1 k12
k4 = 1.4*10**3 #M**-3 s**-1  k13
k5 = 3.0*10**9 #M**-1 s**-1  k14
k6 = 2.6*10**5 #M**-2 s**-1 k15
k7 = 3.494     #M**-1 s**-1   kc5
k8 = 2.0*10**3 #M**-1 s**-1  kd1

#L(0) = #[I-]
#L(1) = #[I2]
#L(2) = #[HOI]
#L(3) = #[H+]
#L(4) = #[H2O]
#L(5) = #[HOIO]
#L(6) = #[IO3-]
#L(7) = #[O2]
#L(8) = #[CH2(COOH)2]
#L(9) = #[CHI(COOH)2]
#L(10) = #[H2O2]


def BR(L,t):
    H1=k1*L[2]*L[0]*L[3]
    H2=k2*L[1]*L[4]
    H3=k3*L[3]*L[5]*L[0]
    H4=k4*(L[3]**2)*L[6]*L[1]
    H5=k5*L[5]**2
    H6=k6*L[7]*L[6]*L[5]
    H7=k7*L[8]*L[1]
    H8=k8*L[2]*L[10]

    dCdt = -H1 + H2 + (2*H3) + H4 + H5 - H8
    dAdt = -H1 + H2 - H3 - H4 + H7 + H8 
    dDdt = -H1 + H2 - H3 - (2*H4) + H5 - H6 + H7 + H8 
    dBdt = H1-H2-H7
    dEdt = H1-H2+H8 
    dFdt = -H3 + H4 - (2*H5) + H6
    dGdt = -H4 + H5 + H6 
    dHdt = H6  
    dIdt = -H7 
    dJdt = H7
    dKdt = H8 
    return(dCdt,dAdt,dBdt,dDdt,dEdt,dFdt,dGdt,dHdt,dIdt,dJdt,dKdt)
t = np.arange(0,100,1)
L0 = [0,0.02,0.04,0,1,0.04,0,0,10.06,0,0.5]
Conc= odeint(BR,L0,t)
cC= Conc[:,0]
cA= Conc[:,1]
cD= Conc[:,2]
cB= Conc[:,3]
cE= Conc[:,4]
cF= Conc[:,5]
cG= Conc[:,6]
cH= Conc[:,7]
cI= Conc[:,8]
cJ= Conc[:,9]
cK= Conc[:,10]

plt.plot(t,cA)
plt.plot(t,cB)
plt.plot(t,cC)
plt.plot(t,cD)
plt.plot(t,cE)
plt.plot(t,cF)
plt.plot(t,cG)
plt.plot(t,cH)
plt.plot(t,cI)
plt.plot(t,cJ)
plt.plot(t,cK)
```

Comment: The order of components seems different in the derivative and in the itemization for the plot. Please check for consistency.

Comment: Also, could you possibly add the chemical reactions as comments to the computations of the `H`'s? And possibly add the line `A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,J,J,K = L` as the first line in `BR` and replace the `L` components by the separately named variables.

Comment: Is this http://www.math.udel.edu/~rossi/Math512/2003/br5.pdf the equation or even a source of yours?

Comment: Thank you will try stuff above. Its really frustrating this part is the only thing missing in my thesis.

Comment: I added my own variant of implementing the model and the results I got. I got nothing sensible for your initial values, physically impossible large results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the inconsistencies mentioned in the comments, you can work around the inner step limit by either decreasing the time step or by increasing the

```
mxstep
```

parameter. At the same time you should contemplate if the default tolerances of about `1e-6` are sufficient for your purposes or if you need better accuracy,

```
Conc= odeint(BR,L0,t, atol=1e-7, rtol=1e-11, mxstep=5000)
```

---

Restoring the order of increasing  letters, the assignment of reactants should be

```
A: HOI, B: I-, C: H+, D: I2, E: H2O
```

and then the same as per your code. The chemical equations are

```
A + B + C <--> E + F,     ->: k1 = 3.1e12, <-: k2 = 2.2
B + C + F --> 2A          k3 = 5e9
B + 2C + G --> A + F      k4 = 1.4e3
2F --> A + C + G          k5 = 3e9
C + F + G -- 2F + 0.5H    k6 = 2.6e5
D + I --> B + C + J       k7 = 3.494
A + K --> B + C + E + H   k8 = 2e3
```

This should result in a function

```
def BR(L,t):
    A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K = L
    H1 = k1*A*B*C
    H2 = k2*D*E
    H3 = k3*B*C*F
    H4 = k4*B*C**2*F
    H5 = k5*F**2
    H6 = k6*C*F*G
    H7 = k7*D*I
    H8 = k8*A*K 

    dAdt = -H1 + H2 + 2*H3 + H4 + H5 - H8
    dBdt = -H1 + H2 -H3 - H4 + H7 + H8
    dCdt = -H1 + H2 - H3 -2*H4 + H5 - H6 + H7 + H8
    dDdt = H1 - H2 + H7 
    dEdt = H1 - H2 + H8
    dFdt = -H3 + H4 - (2*H5) + H6
    dGdt = -H4 + H5 + H6
    dHdt = 0.5*H6 + H8
    dIdt = -H7 #[CH2(COOH)2] se porablja
    dJdt = H7 #[CHI(COOH)2]nastaja
    dKdt = -H8 #[H2O2] nastaja
    return(dAdt,dBdt,dCdt,dDdt,dEdt,dFdt,dGdt,dHdt,dIdt,dJdt,dKdt)

L0 = [ 8e-11, 1e-10, 0.056, 8e-8, 1, 9e-11, 0.01, 2.5e3, 0.0015, 0, 0.33 ]
t = np.arange(0,2000,1)
Conc= odeint(BR,L0,t)
names = [ '[HOI]', '[I-]', '[H+]', '[I2]', '[H2O]', '[HOIO]', '[IO3-]', '[O2]','[CH2(COOH)2]','[CHI(COOH)2]','[H2O2]']

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4,wspace=0.55)
for k, name in enumerate(names):
    plt.subplot(6,2,k+1);
    plt.plot(t,Conc[:,k])
    plt.title(name)
plt.show()
```

(initial values from http://www.math.udel.edu/~rossi/Math512/2003/br5.pdf) giving results

[image]

Comment: One last question, sorry about that. How did you plot all the equations seperatly. :)

Comment: The first reaction, A + B + C -> E + F (A=[HOI], B=[I-], C=[H+], E=[H2O], F=[HOIO]) doesn't balance.

Comment: @xnx : That is obviously true. As far as I remember I could not find a reference for exactly this model, so my reaction system resulted from solving a kind of letter riddle. The state space in the question was inconsistent, and my attempt to correct that can be wong.

Comment: it seems to be a corrupted version of the simplified BR model from Kim, Lee and Shin, JCP 117, 2710 (2002), but without treating the flow terms properly (or at all) and with HOIO swapped for I2 and H2O treated as a reactant somehow. I don't think it's recoverable in its current form. I wonder how user9280977's Master's thesis went...